# Spring Boot Reactive - register user

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming

Reactive programming is kind of hard to understand for me. My use case - I would like to register a user (save it to DB) only in case the user with the given email doesn't exist in DB. I have a function in Kotlin in a Spring Boot service:

```
    fun registerUser2(userDto: UserDto): Mono<PersonalUser> {
        return personalUserRepository.findByEmail(userDto.email!!)
            .switchIfEmpty(
                personalUserRepository.save(toEntity(userDto))
            ).flatMap {
                Mono.empty()
            }
    }
```

Then in the Controller I want to react on an empty `Mono` to distinguish between

- user was created, and
- user cannot be created if it already exists.

```
    @PostMapping("/reg")
    fun register(@RequestBody user: UserDto): Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> {
        return userService2.registerUser2(user)
            .flatMap { Mono.just(ResponseEntity("User[username: ${it!!.username}, password: you cant see me, email: ${it.email}, first name: ${it.firstName}, last name: ${it.lastName}]", HttpStatus.CREATED)) }
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity("User with this email already exist", HttpStatus.FOUND)))
    }
```

Repository method is

```
fun findByEmail(email: String): Mono<PersonalUser>
```

Saving is working. So it saves first time. Second time not. But I am getting always `Mono.empty()` and therefore all the time `HttpStatus.FOUND`. It looks like `switchIfEmpty` is not like an if statement and therefore it continues to `flatMap`. I tried many changes, but it is still not working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @shy-albatross, yeah, it was strategy I was trying but explicitly like when `findByEmail` is empty throw my RuntimeException etc.

Final solution so easy, but really it took me days.

```
fun registerUser(userDto: UserDto): Mono<PersonalUser> {
    return personalUserRepository.save(toEntity(userDto))
        .onErrorResume { Mono.empty() }
}
```

Plus that `UNIQUE` constraint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse if you call

```
.flatMap {
   Mono.empty()
 }
```

it will always return an empty mono.

I would try something like

```
personalUserRepository.findByEmail(userDto.email!!)
        .flatMap{Mono.error()}
        .switchIfEmpty(
            personalUserRepository.save(toEntity(userDto))
        )
```

so if the user is found, it return an error, if not it creates the user, because the `flatMap` after `findByEmail` would be executed at subscribtion time only if the mono returned by `findByEmail` is not empty.

Comment: flatMap can't compile. Type mismatch. Required: Mono<out TypeVariable(R)!>!
Found: Unit

Comment: Your database should have a unique constraint on the email, so I would just let the save operation error on that, and catch it if necessary

Comment: Yeah I wrote directly on the website not using the IDE. I guess the type cannot be inferred automatically.